# Why does apache2 default to LANG=C instead of UTF8 or system default

Tags: apache2, locale, encoding, utf-8

The 10-year-old comment in `/etc/apache2/envvars` simply says "The locale used by some modules like mod_dav", but why can't mod_dav be fixed to also handle a better LANG setting for the rest of apache?